# How can I fix this account creation/sign in problem with Pokemon Trainer Club?

Tags: pokemon-tcg-online

I want to create a pokemon trainer club account for online trading game. I have an account with my google mail id in Pokemon Go. When I try to create a new account using same mail Id I get this error :

> There is a problem with your email address. Please verify that it is spelled correctly. If it is not, please correct it and try again. If you already have a Pokémon Trainer Club account with this email address, please use the Forgot Password Tool to find your account.

But when I try to reset password or click on forgot username I get account no found error.

> Unable to find an account using the provided information.
> Are you a Pokémon GO player? If so, you may have signed in with your Google account.

I remember my username but password reset is not working nor I can create a new account. How can I resolve this?